# Python / Odoo 8.0 Get unsaved tree list

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Can someone help me:

I need to get the purchase.order.line's from the `purchase.order` form.
Getting saved order lines is no problem.

> Problem is to get the tree-view lines from the unsaved form in the `onchange` function of the parent purchase.order (on `partner_id`).

I'm unable to find or to get this. 
I'm able to get the tuples but not the complete order-line. When I update the line manually, I cannot save the changes.

Edit:
I need a way to modify/update a new added order.line entry on changing the partner.

Comment: What you need to do?, you can treat two ways of onchanges, the one of the purchase.order.line object or the one2many in purchase.order, but specify a bit more